# Maven assembly plugin - is there any other way to achieve this?

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using the assembly plugin in Maven to package up not only the delivery in question, but the relevant dependencies to make a stand alone deliverable which can be deployed on any target device.

It happens to be a zip file for a Windows target but the technique covers jars etc.

Unfortunately, in doing this, the tool was bring in 2nd, 3rd and 4th level dependencies increasing the number of files packaged for one delivery this meant instead of packaging up 10 libraries I had a zip including  52 jar files!

Reading round this subject, I found that the assembly plugin had a couple of parameters specified in the `<dependency>` section,  *useProjectArtifact* and *useTransitiveDependencies* could be set to prevent this happening:

```
<assembly …>
…
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
    …
    <dependency>
      <outputDirectory>…</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
    </dependency>
    …
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
…
</assembly>
```

This works beautifully.
My question is, is there any other way to do this, please?

Comment: If the libraries you're using depend transitively on some other libraries, and you didn't declare it in your own POM, not including them in the assembly will fail at run-time with a lot of `NoClassDefFoundError`... Also, why are you looking for another way?

Comment: Thanks Tunaki.  Actually, that's not happening when I am running them, it all seems to be good.